# Why shaders doesn't includes to build?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new in Unity and there is something looks weird to me. I created a `UnlitTextureYUV.shader` file then I use it in my script like this

```
...
meshRenderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("UnlitTextureYUV"));
...
```

Then in editor I click on run button and I see that everything is working properly, ok. Then I click `File->Build&Run` and I get an error `ArgumentNullException` that means shader not found.

I tried to find out what is going on and found such answer on Unity community

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1147277/textures-from-local-works-in-editor-missing-in-bui.html

As far as I understand in order to use shaders in build dynamically I need to create dummy material add texture to it and even create dummy object (disabled) and add this material to this object. In this order my shader will be included in build and I will be able to find it dynamically in code by invoke this method  `Shader.Find("UnlitTextureYUV")`.

Question is - is there more straight way to include shader in build? Why I need to create dummy objects in order to include this file in build? Or I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add all your shaders to Unity's 'Always included shaders' list in the
[graphic settings](http://stalhandske.dk/UnityDocs/Manual/class-GraphicsSettings.html).

Comment: I found `Graphic settings` here `Edit->ProjectSettings->Graphics->AlwaysIncludedShaders`